# MVC/WCF and Ado net Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a web service(WCF) that is using Ado .net Entity framework for database operation.I Generate all the entity using this framework. So my question is Can I use these models generated by the Entity framework to my MVC application just referencing a Web service ? If it is ok then it stops writing Model on MVC framework which saves lots of time.

To summarize and make it clear,
Can a wcf proxy client be used as a view model of the mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, add a service reference to your WCF service, define a repository interface that will represent the operations you could perform with your model classes and in the implementation of this interface simply call the service by using the autogenerated proxy client.

Now all that's left is to have view models that will fill the gap between the views and the models that come from your WCF service.

In fact in a properly designed ASP.NET MVC application a controller should never know where the data comes from: it could be a SQL Database, some ORM Framework, a remote service, ... All that the controller should work with this contract you have defined (repository) and map between the view models and the actual models. The actual data manipulation should be performed by the specific implementation of your repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use those EF generated models as a "View Model" directly into my mvc application?

Answer (score 1):

Move the generated Entity models to a separate assembly and reference the assembly from both projects.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can**. MVC by default removes EF-specific [properties](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx).

> In the first section, we define a
>   ShouldShow method which is pulled
>   right out of the logic for our default
>   Object template. You’ll notice there’s
>   mention of System.Data.EntityState
>   (defined in the
>   System.Data.Entity.dll) which is used
>   to **filter out certain Entity Framework**
>   properties. If you aren’t using Entity
>   Framework you can safely delete that
>   line. You’ll know you don’t need that
>   line if you aren’t referencing
>   System.Data.Entity.dll which will
>   cause this code to blow up like
>   aluminum foil in a microwave.

Comment: Thanks but I am more concerned over the Models (proxy client) that is generated by EF and exposed on a wcf web service, can I use them as a "view model" on my mvc web app.